# Atualizar propriedade exportada no nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

Tô passando meu app feito no electronjs (nodejs) para o padrão MVC e encontrei um problema na hora de atualizar uma propriedade exportada.

**Exemplo** do meu `application.js`:

```
// Importa os módulos privados
const config  = require('./config/config');
const loading = require('./controllers/loading-controller');
const main    = require('./controllers/main-controller');

app.on('ready', function () {
  loading.createWindow(__dirname);
  main.createWindow(__dirname);
  setTimeout(function(){ 
      loading.window.close();
      main.window.show();
  }, 3000);
});
```

**Exemplo** do meu `loading-controller.js`:

```
// Importa o model
const loading = require('../models/loading');

let loadingWindow;

module.exports = {
  createWindow: function (dir) {
    loadingWindow = new BrowserWindow(loading);
  },
  window: loadingWindow
}
```

O problema ocorre quando eu tento executar os métodos `close();` e `show();` nas minhas janelas, pois elas estão dadas como `undefined` — que é perfeitamente lógico, visto que foi o estado padrão que passei para elas.

Como eu atualizo essa propriedade após executar a *function* responsável por armazenar a `BrowserWindow` nela?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você poderia fazer assim:

```
// Importa o model
const loading = require('../models/loading');

let loadingWindow;

const exported = {
  createWindow: function (dir) {
    exported.window = loadingWindow = new BrowserWindow(loading);
  },
  window: loadingWindow
};

module.exports = exported;
```

Mas talvez fosse melhor você manter esse estado interno a uma instância do seu módulo.

**EDIT**

Pra esclarecer meu último comentário. Na sua implementação, se você chamar `createWindow` mais de uma vez, a referência para a `new BrowserWindow` vai ser perdida. Se você usar o loading-controller apenas uma vez, tudo bem, mas se um módulo usar uma vez, e outro módulo usar em seguida, os dois vão estar referenciando a mesma `window`, e nesse caso a `window` criada pela segunda chamada. A primeira `window` vai permanecer na memória até ser fechada.

Se você está querendo que a `window` apareça apenas uma vez, talvez fosse melhor deixar isso explícito no código. Por exemplo, ao chamar `createWindow`, instanciar uma nova `window` apenas se `loadingWindow === null`.

Comment: Continuo recebendo como undefined, Thiago :/
E como assim manter o estado a uma instância do módulo?
Desculpa, mas sou leigo e iniciei hoje mesmo com padrão MVC e NodeJS.

Comment: Daniel, você alterou conforme minha sugestão nos dois módulos (controllers/loading-controller e controllers/main-controller)?

Comment: Agora que vi que precisava igualar a window exportada com a window que estava rodando na function, e funcionou que é uma beleza! Obrigado, Thiago.